# Issue with YAML Header in R markdown File

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am trying to create a Flex Dashboard using R markdown. Once I start executing the code I see many error listed below:

[image: YAML Header Error in .Rmd File]

The Code after the YAML header is executed with no issues and because of  the error above I am not able to get a flex dashboard as an output.

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is, that you want to execute the YAML header in a R script. When you use RStudio, then go to 'File' -> 'New File' -> 'R Markdown' and enter the YAML header and your code. Then you can render your RMD file via `CTRL+Shift+K` or in the console via `rmarkdown::render("<path-to-your-file>")`.

If you do not use RStudio, save the script as a Rmd file (`*.Rmd`) file and render it via console.

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I used the command "rmarkdown::render("<path-to-your-file>")"  and the code is showing no error now!